# Google Maps not using Latest Renderer Emulator on Certain API Levels

Tags: android, google-maps

I cannot force the latest renderer to work with certain API levels on the emulator with the following code:

```
MapsInitializer.initialize(applicationContext, MapsInitializer.Renderer.LATEST, this)
```

With API level 30, I can get the latest renderer working.
Google Play services client version: 18020000
Google Play services package version: 231715037
Google Play services maps renderer version(maps_core): 231112103

With API level 34, I am forced to use legacy renderer:
Google Play services client version: 18020000
Google Play services package version: 231818044
Google Play services maps renderer version(legacy): 203115000

Both of these devices are setup the exact same except for the API level. To me, this seems backwards, that a newer Android version is causing the app to use the older renderer.

I created my app using the Google Maps Views Activity wizard

```
class MapsActivity : AppCompatActivity(), OnMapReadyCallback, OnMapsSdkInitializedCallback {

    private lateinit var mMap: GoogleMap
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMapsBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        MapsInitializer.initialize(applicationContext, MapsInitializer.Renderer.LATEST, this)

        binding = ActivityMapsBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        val mapFragment = supportFragmentManager
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)
    }

    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap
        
        val coordinates = LatLng(39.999495, -83.012685)
        mMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(coordinates).title("Marker"))
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(coordinates))
    }

    override fun onMapsSdkInitialized(renderer: MapsInitializer.Renderer) {
        when (renderer) {
            MapsInitializer.Renderer.LATEST -> Log.d("MapsDemo", "The latest version of the renderer is used.")
            MapsInitializer.Renderer.LEGACY -> Log.d("MapsDemo", "The legacy version of the renderer is used.")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I did create an issue on Google's issuetracker at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/327248427

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's what I had to do in order to get the emulator using the LATEST renderer:

You're using a virtual device with Google Play.
you have finished the set up your device prompt to enable Google Play.